# Using Skimage adaptive thresholding on an image and getting the output

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, image-thresholding

I am trying to use scikit-image's adaptive threshold on my image. I tested out their sample code from [HERE](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_threshold_adaptive.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, threshold_adaptive


image = data.page()

global_thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
binary_global = image > global_thresh

block_size = 35
binary_adaptive = threshold_adaptive(image, block_size, offset=10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(7, 8))
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes
plt.gray()

ax0.imshow(image)
ax0.set_title('Image')

ax1.imshow(binary_global)
ax1.set_title('Global thresholding')

ax2.imshow(binary_adaptive)
ax2.set_title('Adaptive thresholding')

for ax in axes:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The code takes in a sample image, thresholds it and shows it using plt. However, I am trying to retrieve the numpy array of the thresholded image. When I tried using `cv2.imwrite` on the variable `binary_global`, it does not work. When printing out `binary_global`--it is actually an array consisting of False and True values rather than numbers. I am not sure how plt can use that and produce an image. Regardless, how can I threshold the image and retrieve the new thresholded image's array with the RGB values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need convert the scikit image to opencv to be able to use `cv2.imwrite()`.

Add the following changes-

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, threshold_adaptive
import cv2


image = data.page()

global_thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
binary_global = image > global_thresh

block_size = 35
binary_adaptive = threshold_adaptive(image, block_size, offset=10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(7, 8))
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes
plt.gray()

ax0.imshow(image)
ax0.set_title('Image')

ax1.imshow(binary_global)
ax1.set_title('Global thresholding')

ax2.imshow(binary_adaptive)
ax2.set_title('Adaptive thresholding')

for ax in axes:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
img = img_as_ubyte(binary_global)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can then use the `img` for writing etc.

Comment: Also see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html#working-with-opencv